# Nginx rewrite to ignore letters added after URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am currently writing the nginx rewrite to ingore any letters in url .

For example my application url is:

```
http://example.com/downloads
```

Rewrite to ignore anything else added after actual url and redirect to actual url

```
http://example.come/downloads/123 ==> http://example.come/downloads
http://example.come/downloads/abc ==> http://example.come/downloads
http://example.come/downloads/a1b2c3 ==> http://example.come/downloads
```

Comment: Your example rewrites from `/download/...` to `/downloads` - should that be `/downloads/...` to `/downloads`? Try: `rewrite ^/downloads/ /downloads redirect;`

Comment: Thank Richard for pointing the mistake . I corrected . I testing the redirect . 